# I am not being able to push files in remote git rep

Tags: git, github

I am not being able to push files in remote rep (Mac el capitan; git version 2.13.1; also tried with version 2.10.1 but same result). Tried out with both https and SSH file options.
Please help. [screenshot is given here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av4mn.png)

Comment: Well, in both cases it fails due to lack of proper credentials, have you configured your ssh keys (for the last attempt) or set up your username and password (for the first attempt)? Seems git says "no".

Comment: You omitted the login process. Insert your username and password for github and then after authorization you will be able to push

Comment: @Karlsen, Thank you so much! Configured my SSH key and I'm being able to push files now!  :D

Comment: @Parantap, thanks. Problem resolved!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this manual how to generate and add ssh key to github https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Then try again